# How to install new software on Ubuntu 12.04 LTS?

Tags: command-line, software-installation

I am a new user of Ubuntu. What command can I use to install something using the terminal?

Comment: Why not use software-center?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just type this on your terminal:

```
sudo apt-get install [package name]
```

And you also can install a new software on Software Center. It is easy to use.

Comment: Software Center is great, i can search software i want to install from there, thanks for helping me

Answer (score 0):

```
sudo apt-get install here_comes_the_packagename
```

But better read into some "newbie" tutorials and check the Ubuntu documentation: https://help.ubuntu.com/

Comment: Apt-get is not recommended for noobs, let them use usc

Comment: That's a matter of opinion. He wanted to know which terminal command it is. So the question is answered correctly.

Comment: I suggest not to use asterisks in the example command. It will expand to all packages containing that keyword in the package name.

Comment: erm... I did not want to tell the user to use an asterisk. It was just like a $packagename instead of *packagename*. It seems to confuse some people so I change it immediately.